# How to create properly sql query (string) for PreparedStatement with values which are repeated in query?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have query like this

```sql
BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM some_table with(nolock) 
    WHERE col_1 = ? and col_2 = ? and col_3 = ?)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO some_table (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6,
            col_7, col_8, col_9, col_10, col_11, col_12, cdate) 
        VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, convert(date, GETDATE()))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE some_table 
        SET col_4 = col_4 + ?,
            col_5 = col_5 + ?,
            col_6 = col_6 + ?,
            col_7 = col_7 + ?,
            col_8 = col_8 + ?,
            col_9 = col_9 + ?,
            col_10 = col_10 + ?,
            col_11 = ?
        WHERE col_1 = ? and col_2 = ? and col_3 = ?
    END
END
```

And because of some requirements I have to keep this `Query` in `String`, what is already very painful for me. But I created `PreparedStatement` for this, which look like this:

```java
PreparedStatement preparedStatemnt = conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery)) {
preparedStatemnt.setInt(1, value1);
preparedStatemnt.setString(2, value2);
preparedStatemnt.setString(3, value3);

preparedStatemnt.setInt(4, value1);
preparedStatemnt.setString(5, value2);
preparedStatemnt.setString(6, value3);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(7, value4);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(8, value5);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(9, value6);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(10, value7);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(11, value8);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(12, value9);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(13, value10);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(14, value11);
preparedStatemnt.setString(15, value12);

preparedStatemnt.setInt(16, value4);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(17, value5);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(18, value6);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(19, value7);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(20, value8);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(21, value9);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(22, value10);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(23, valye11);
preparedStatemnt.setInt(24, value1);
preparedStatemnt.setString(25, value2);
preparedStatemnt.setString(26, value3);
```

like you can see in here value which I have to put can be repeated and I would prefer to avoid it, but I do not know if there is any possibility.

And here is my question is there any way to create this statements in a way a `String.fromat` works, I mean

```java
String.format("%1s, %1s, %1s, %1s", value1); // so the First(1) value is putted into all 4 places
```

I was thinking about using `String.format` to create them but I almost sure is not secure, is it? Or maybe someone can give me other suggestion how to deal with statement like this, it would be really helpful, cause I have many queries like this which I have to create.

Ps. I can not use stored procedures.

Comment: No, `format` is not secure. Nothing prevents you from creating helper methods to "multi-set" parameters on the `PreparedStatement` though, but you're polishing a turd here. The end result won't be pretty, no matter what you do, so weigh carefully the amount of time and energy you're wasting on this.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks, I thought so, someone will say something like this, and creating methods for each statement I think is pointless, cause I will use it any way only in one place, but creating extra 20+ methods make no sense. But I am glad I could confirm my thoughts. I will stop "polishing a turd" ;)

Comment: With helper methods like `setInts(ps, value, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7)` you could cut the lines a little bit depending on the amount of redundancy, but that's about the best you can do.